# Installing bottlepy and running python script

Tags: python, macos, easy-install, bottle

I am trying to run this simple python script through my terminal window:(it is the example on the bottlepy website)

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/:name')
def index(name='World'):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

In order to do so, I installed bottlepy from Terminal using

```
easy_install bottle
```

which instals it in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/4.2.30201/bin

When I try to run my python document in my terminal window:

```
cd ~/Dropbox/Work/MongoDB/
python hello.py
```

It returns:

```
ImportError: No module named bottle
```

I'm not sure what to do to put bottlepy in the correct emplacement so that it works. I'm sure it must be something silly but I can't think of what to do.
Thank you!!
xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#installation). You can download bottle.py directly to the folder with the rest of the progs, or install in the way shown.

Comment: note: the docs recommend `sudo easy_install` that could be unwise thing to do because it might break packages that you're not even aware. The option that uses virtualenv is safe and flexible `wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py`

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the file mostly you need to create app first:

```
app = bottle.Bottle()
```

And later run it or serve by external web server like waitress